# Round off the data frame in Pyspark

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

i am trying to round off "perc_of_count_total" column in pyspark, but i could not do it, below is my script,

```
Auto_data1 = Auto_data.groupBy("Make", "Fuel") \
            .count() \
            .withColumnRenamed('count', 'cnt_per_group') \
            .withColumn('perc_of_count_total',  (F.col('cnt_per_group') / tot) * 100 ) \
            .show(10)

Auto_data1.select(round(col('cnt_per_group'),2)).show(5)
```

Output

```
+-----------+----+-------------+--------------------+
|       Make|Fuel|cnt_per_group|       perc_of_count|
+-----------+----+-------------+--------------------+
|  C        |   I|        34748|0.027960585487965286|
|  P        |   D|          489| 3.93482396213164E-4|
```

Error message

```
An error was encountered:
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'select'
Traceback (most recent call last):
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'select'
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the last `show` function, it doesn't return anything.

Comment: Same error i am getting, plz suggest a another way to do it,

Comment: Please give some sample data.

Comment: Hi, i have given the output table. In that table "perc_of_count" column want to make 3 decimal place.

Comment: Keep three decimal places.the second piece of data ```perc_of_count``` is ```0.000```, and keep 4 decimal places as follows:```import pyspark.sql.functions as F df_round = df.withColumn('perc_of_count', F.round(F.col('perc_of_count').cast('decimal(38,20)'), 4))
df_round.show(truncate=False)```